# How to identify the Excel custom property is exists or not?

Tags: c#

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

I am using a method to set Excel custom property but if the property already exists it throws exception, and also how i can update the property if it already exists

```
public Excel.Workbook workBk;
Application _excelApp;

public void SetDocumentProperty(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    try
    {
        _excelApp = new Application();
        workBk = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\12345.xlsx",
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        object oDocCustomProps = workBk.CustomDocumentProperties;
        Type typeDocCustomProps = oDocCustomProps.GetType();

         object[] oArgs = {propertyName,false,
         MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString,
         propertyValue};

         typeDocCustomProps.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.Default |
                                       BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,
                                       oDocCustomProps, oArgs);
         workBk.Save();
    }
    finally
    {
         workBk.Close(false, @"C:\12345.xlsx", null);
         Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBk);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string [] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory);
```

u can use server mappath if u puting the excel file in u project like this 
  string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~\upload"));

this line will give u all the files that already exist in a directory this way u can check if file already exist without getting an exception

Comment: i don't wanna get files. I just want to get metadata of excel file and set custom properties

Comment: well this way u can see if the name u trying to save with then u should deal with that accordingly 
1. u can leave it and save file somewhere else
2.delete the old file and save one in his place 
       System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(directory + filename );
     that would delete the file

Comment: that it is not my question